# swt versus swing judged from a performance/speed standpoint (yes, this one is a classic :D)

Tags: performance, swing, user-interface, swt, benchmarking

Lately i've been  looking to see which of the above contestants is better performance-wise and i've found a rather interesting article that demolishes SWT's performance rating compared to swing's : http://cosylib.cosylab.com/pub/CSS/DOC-SWT_Vs._Swing_Performance_Comparison.pdf . It's worth mentioning that the  benchmark was done in 2005 and since then things might have changed (dunno in who's favor tho ) SO:

1)does anybody know any performance tests  done recently? (2-3 years at most :D)
2) your personal experience on this matter is invaluable to me so do tell if you noticed differences between swing and swt when it comes to performance

Comment: wow...so there are no recent performance comparison between the two? O_o

Comment: *"so do tell if you noticed differences"*  Sure.  But not between the toolkits.  The one that runs faster will be the one that has better programmers & better client code.

Comment: @Andrew this is exactly what I wanted to say!

Comment: @jfpoilpret It seems you & me beat everyone else (1) to state the obvious.  (1) Including all those who read this without replying, and those that saw the thread title and thought *Not another (bloody) A vs. B GUI toolkit microsecond performance question!* and went directly to the **next** question.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson  a  speed ratio of  2000 (in  favor of swing) when it comes to table widgets is a little alarming though, even if we are only talking about Java 1.5 on Linux. And BTW those microseconds tend to add up :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an perfect comparison, but [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) have some possibilities to benchmark GUI performance. See *Using the MigLayout Demos for GUI Benchmarking* part on [official sites](http://www.miglayout.com/).

It's also good way to check the miglayout GUI benchmarks under profiler to see memory usage of SWT/Swing. That's a huge difference.

Anyway, I agree with comment from Andrew Thompson: *"The one that runs faster will be the one that has better programmers & better client code"*

Answer (score 0):

The one that runs faster will be the one that has better programmers & better client code.

Sure, that's a good point.  The human factor is very important for performance (& usabilty, maintainability, and ALL functional & non-functional qualities).  But the OP was specifically asking about technological/tool differences...

We can take the human factor out of the mix by assuming the designers/programmers are a fixed group and will apply similar skills against both APIs.  Or we can apply a standard benchmark test to measure difference in behaviour between the to APIs, as per http://cosylib.cosylab.com/pub/CSS/DOC-SWT_Vs._Swing_Performance_Comparison.pdf .

This leaves a very valid question.  What are the objective differences between Swing & SWT?  Would be good to see a thorough 'objective' performance benchmark test from last 2 or 3 years.  To me this Q's alive.